How to run a ratpack server with maven and gplus?
I'm trying to run a ratpack server by using groovy and maven.
(You can find the source code here.
import static ratpack.groovy.Groovy.ratpack
...

ratpack {
  handlers {
    ...

    // Service execution endpoint
    get("execute") {
      render "result"
    }
  }
}

There's a way to avoid ending the execution using gplus ? or maybe there's another way to launch it ?
I tried to use gplus to launch the server. Here's an extract of my pom.xml:
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
    <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>execute</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.23</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
        <scripts>
            <script>src/main/groovy/Main.groovy</script>
        </scripts>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

but it seems that after maven finishes the build, it gracefully stops it.
> mvn gplus:execute        
...
[INFO] Running Groovy script from \open-api-ratpack\src\main\groovy\Main.groovy.
[INFO] Starting server...
[INFO] Building registry...
...
Ratpack started for http://localhost:5050
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.361 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-10-24T11:29:26+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Stopping server...
[INFO] Server stopped.


